# How to scroll programmatically in Cordova / Capacitor / Conic using vanilla js

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I did search a lot and didn't find an acceptable response so here's the problem and my solution for other people who are struggling at that.

The problem: we can't use anymore `window.scrollTo()`, to scroll programmatically it's disabled for performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: so we need to make something like this:

[image]

The top div should be place at top level (and there should be only one top div) in the html with following css:

```
.div-scrollable {
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
}
```

like this we're able to use the top div to scroll and here the command to do it nicely:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('div-scrollable')[0].scrollTo({ top: y, behavior: 'smooth' })
```

Cheers!